# How to convert a Python text file containing lists of lists into a list of lists?

Tags: python, parsing

This seems pretty straightforward, but I can't find any alternative solutions online.  I have a text file like so:

```
[[[0, 0, 'no'], [3, 0, 1]], [[4, 4, 'coming']]]
[[[0, 0, 'yes'], [2, 0, 2], [2, 2, '15-19']], [[9, 4, 'not coming']]]
```

How do I go about parsing this file in such a way where it'd follow the same logic:

```
# Read in file
# Work with the first line, or list, of lists 
    # Do this by putting it into a temporary list of lists variable
```

Is what I'm asking possible?  I'm just wanting to save myself time working with a monstrous text file that'd be way easier this way.

Comment: What about `eval()`?

Comment: Did you creaate the text file or is it third-party?

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is safer to parse a list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to parser the file:

```
from pprint import pprint
from ast import literal_eval

data = []
with open('<your file.txt>', 'r') as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        data.extend(literal_eval('[' + line + ']'))

pprint(data)
```

Prints:

```
[[[[0, 0, 'no'], [3, 0, 1]], [[4, 4, 'coming']]],
 [[[0, 0, 'yes'], [2, 0, 2], [2, 2, '15-19']], [[9, 4, 'not coming']]]]
```